# Dust.js get call count of helper in template

Tags: javascript, dust.js, dust-helpers

So I have a `dust.js` helper which requires some `jsx` module when called and afterwards renders this module as html (some kind of plugin).

```
{@react type="Text"\}
...
<some Markup>
...
{@react type="Text"\}
{@react type="Text"\}
```

Meanwhile I have a data structure which contains all the elements that should be rendered on this template (a page)

```
['1st', '2nd', '3rd']
```

In my helper I'd like to know how often I called `@react`. Like incrementing a counter on the context which all helpers called within this template can access.

I was fiddeling around with `context.pop()` and `context.push` but wasn't able to mutate the template's context. Every helper gets it's own. So I either need a way to get the call count of the helper or store the current number of invocations of the helper somewhere accessible to the other ones.

However, when doing sth like `{@react type="Text" index=0\}` and afterwards accessing it with `context.get(['page', 'elements', params.index])` it works (of course). But this enforces me to keep count of the elements I am disposing (especially annoying when adding and removing elements)

Hope s/o has an idea, maybe I'm just missing sth really simple.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special `global` object attached to each Context that contains references you'd like to be available everywhere in your template.

For more information, see [Context Globals](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/contexts/#context-globals).

You prepopulate the global by calling `dust.context({ foo: 'bar' })` to create a Context object. You can pass this to Dust in your render step instead of a plain Object.

Inside any helper, you can access the global directly to set properties on it:

```
react: function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var numTimesCalled = ++context.global.numTimesCalled;
});
```

You can use properties in the global in your template. You can think of them as being at the "lowest" level in the context stack.

Comment: Yeah also tried the global thing but didn't think of calling `dust.context`. Will try. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Since I just need the invocation count in the helper I used `dust.context(null, {numTimesCalled: 0}` so that it's hidden from the template (as far as I understood). Nevertheless the `context` solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the `options` (second argument) is hidden from the template and is exactly for scenarios like that.